# Easy question, but what is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I recognize $\mathbb R^n$ to be every single possible vector in $\mathbb R^n$, but a subset is any of those points right? So technically a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ can be just {[0, 1]}, right?

Well then it's pretty obvious that any subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ will be a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, but how come we have to state at the start of any "proving it's a subspace" proof by stating that it is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$?

Also am I correct in thinking that a subspace is just a span of a particular "dimension in $\mathbb R^n$"? So a subspace is either a line, plane, hyperplane, etc.?

Comment: The subset has to have the same kind of elements.  So $\{(0,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0\leq y \leq 1\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the unit interval $[0,1]$ is not, because all points in the unit interval have only one dimension.  For example $1/2 \notin \mathbb{R}^2$. But $(0,1/2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. ANd $\{(0,1/2)\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$.  I am assuming by $[0,1]$ you mean the set of all points $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such taht $0\leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: @Michael by [0, 1], I mean the vector [0, 1] being the only vector in the "subset". If that is what the definition of subset means, just any set in $R^n$. So the whole subset, the set { [0, 1] }, is a set that contains just one vector, [0, 1]. So you're saying this wouldn't be considered a subset in $R^n$ because.. well I'm a little confused why not. What do you mean by saying the "unit interval [0, 1]"? Why can't I just say $y = 0$ instead of $0 \leq y \leq 1$

Comment: @ming You can find the definition of 'subset' here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset

Comment: @ming :  A subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is any set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (the subset can have just one point, or 12, or it can be the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself, it can also have _no_ points and that is called the _empty set_).  The comment history above already makes it clear that what I thought you meant by $[0,1]$ was the interval of real numbers between $0$ and $1$, but that is not what you really meant.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the set of $n$-tuples, and defining the operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication on the set (in the 'usual' way)  of these $n$-tuples, we get the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Any 'collection' of elements from this set is by definition a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is also a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff it satisfies certain other conditions (is a vector space when considered on its own).